# TSQL modify() Method changes prefix of xml element

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following XML:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <soapenv:Fault xmlns:m="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <first>value1</first>
                <last>value2</last>
            </soapenv:Fault>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

All i want to do is update the value of `<first>` element using the given XPATH (ignoring prefixs) using below code:

```
     SET ANSI_PADDING ON;            
     SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;            
     declare @xmlTBL table(tmlXML xml);             
     insert into @xmlTBL(tmlXML)            
     values('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <soapenv:Body> <soapenv:Fault xmlns:m="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <first>valuu1</first> <last>value2</last> </soapenv:Fault> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>');  

    UPDATE @xmlTBL SET tmlXML.modify('insert text{"TEST"}  into (/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:Fault/first[1] [not(node()) and not(text())])[1]');
```

The update of Element value works BUT what is also happening is that element `<soapenv:Fault>` has now become `<m:Fault>` as seen below:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <m:Fault xmlns:m="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <first>TEST</first>
                <last>value2</last>
            </m:Fault>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is it possible to archive what i am doing without the prefix being effected?

Comment: From an *information* perspective, nothing has changed. If you're passing this data to something else that isn't using a home-grown, kludgey parser instead of a decent XML library, it should process this data fine. What's inside the `Body` is a `Fault` element from the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`. What local prefix is being used to identify that namespace doesn't matter.

Comment: Problem is, you have the same namespace definition for the `m` prefix which is incorrect.

Comment: @DenisValeev - I wouldn't describe it as incorrect. Redundant, perhaps, but it's perfectly fine for multiple prefixes to be associated with the same namespace.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The additional namespace of different definition is used to add some more custom information to the already strictly defined `Fault` element in the `SOAP` protocol. From that perspective, it is incorrect to use the same namespace definition.

Comment: Guys the imapct of when the prefix is changed is the XPATH don't mathch the XML Payload the came from . For example if the system is giving me an input which is a XML XPATH , that XPATH is then used in another front-end to manipulate elements . The expected element is has soapenv as prefix, but the actual payload as m:prefix.

Comment: You should notice, when you're using XPath, that you have to supply a set of namespaces and prefixes that you're using in your XPath expression. Those **prefixes** don't have to match the **prefixes** used in the original XML.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I realize that - But there is some UI which takes the "XPATH" and compares its existence by matching string to string. So when the actual payload has m:Fault and xpath has m:fault the element is never picked up. I don't have control of that system so have to manage it from my side but not changing the XML payload in any shape or form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare with this:

```
declare @xmlOriginal xml = '
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault xmlns:m="urn:SomeEntity/1.0">
      <faultcode>a</faultcode>
      <faultstring>b</faultstring>
      <faultactor>c</faultactor>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'

declare @xml xml = @xmlOriginal

set @xml.modify('insert text{"TEST"} into (/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:Fault/faultcode[1])[1]')

select @xml, @xmlOriginal
```

Notice that namespace definitions are different.

Comment: So changing the namespace so something different prevents it from being changed but i cannot be modifying attributes or prefixs in any form. These are production payload which i am storing so i need to avoid that. I simply don't want the prefix to be changed

Comment: @techventure then you either need to change the way that message is produced or preprocess every soap message and change the `m` namespace definition.